# Does bisecting an angle in a right triangle halve the opposite side and if so, why?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

For the triangle and half arc shown it is clear that $b=r\sin(\frac{l}{2r})$ where $l$ is the length of the arc and $r$ is the radius.

Does $b = r\sin(\frac{l}{2r})=2r\sin(\frac{l}{4r})$ and why?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems as if your question reduces to the question: under what circumstances is $$\sin(\theta) = 2\sin(\theta/2) = 2\sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos(\theta)}{2}} ~: 0 \leq \theta \leq (90^{\circ})?$$  This simplifies to $$\cos^2(\theta) - 2\cos(\theta) + 1 = 0 =[\cos(\theta) - 1]^2$$ which has the sole root of $\cos(\theta) = 1 \implies \theta = 0^{\circ}.$

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Comment: A bisector is also a median iff the triangle is isosceles. But the question appears to be asking about an approximation in the limit, not an actual equality, though the OP doesn't make that part clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $AB$ be the angle bisector such that $\angle CAB = \angle BAD = \dfrac{l}{4r}$.

Now $\dfrac{BD}{BC} = \dfrac{r}{x}$. For small arc lengths $l$ (precisely $l< r$ ), $x \approx AB \approx r.$

So, $BC \approx BD = \dfrac{b}{2}.$

[image]

Now from triangle $ADB$, $BD =  AB\sin\left(\dfrac{l}{4r}\right) \approx  r\sin\left(\dfrac{l}{4r}\right).$

$b \approx 2r\sin\left(\dfrac{l}{4r}\right).$

> Again, this holds good only under the above stated condition.

You can vary the values and [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iuy55dcxxl)